# When does a fibre bundle induce a long exact sequence in homotopy groups of mapping spaces?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, smooth-manifolds

Given a smooth fibre bundle of (compact, say) manifolds $F \to E \to M$, with $\pi : E \to M$ the projection, and $i_p : F \to E$ the inclusion of $F$ into any fibre $\pi^{-1}(p)$, we get, for any manifold $X$ the following sequence: $$ \mathcal{C}(M, X) \to \mathcal{C}(E, X) \to \mathcal{C}(F, X) $$ where $\Pi : \mathcal{C}(M, X) \to \mathcal{C}(E, X) $ maps $g$ to $g \circ \pi$, and $I_p : \mathcal{C}(E, X) \to \mathcal{C}(F, X) $ maps $f$ to $f \circ i_p$.

Before jumping into my question, here are a few notes. The image of $\Pi$ is all the $F$-invariant maps $f : E \to X$, that is, over each fibre $F$ = $\pi^{-1}(p) \subset E$, $f|_F$ is constant. Thus, the composition $I_p \circ \Pi$ always maps to constant maps. Furthermore, $\Pi$ is clearly injective  <s>and $I_p$ is surjective for all $p \in M$</s> .

And, if we define the kernel of $I_p$ to be the maps $f : E \to X$ such that $I_p (f)$ is constant, we don't get an "exact" sequence since $Im (\Pi)$ is in general a strict subset of $Ker (I_p)$. But we see that $$Im(\Pi) = \bigcap_{p \in M} Ker (I_p).$$

This begs the question, is there a way to make sense of this as a kind of short exact sequence, and thus induce a kind of long exact sequence in homotopy groups of the mapping spaces? I.e. we have
$$ 0 \to \pi_0(\mathcal{C}(M,X)) \to \pi_0(\mathcal{C}(E,X)) \to \pi_0(\mathcal{C}(F,X)) \to \pi_1(\mathcal{C}(M,X)) \to \ldots$$
is exact with the appropriate induced maps from $\Pi$ and $I_p$.

This, in fact, is **not true** in general, as can be seen by the following counterexample. Consider the Hopf fibration $S^1 \to S^3 \to S^2$ and set $X = S^3$. Then already, at the $\pi_0$ level, $Im(\Pi_* ) \neq Ker (I_{p * } )$.

So my question, at last:

> Given a smooth fibre bundle $F \to E \to M$, for what manifolds $X$ is the above sequence long exact in homotopy groups? What are necessary and sufficient conditions on $X$ for this to hold?

Comment: Surjectivity of $I_p$ would imply every map out of $F$ extends to one out of $E$, which is not in general true. For example in the Hopf fiber bundle, take any fiber $S^1$, and the identity map $S^1 \to S^1$. Since our chosen fiber in $S^3$ is an unknot, it bounds a disk embedded in $S^3$, so the identity map $S^1 \to S^1$ extending over $S^3$ would in particular imply it is nullhomotopic, since it would extend over this disk.

Comment: @AleksandarMilivojević You are right, I missed that! I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: My impression is that this usually works better for cofibrations rather than fibrations. Namely, given a cofibration $i: A\to Y$ we always get a fibration of mapping spaces $i^*:\mathcal{C}(Y,X)\to \mathcal{C}(A,X)$, and can sometimes identify the fiber with some kind of mapping space out of the cofiber of $i$.

Answer (score 3):

We can form the mapping cone $F \to E \to E/F$, and as Mark Grant says, that's where we really have a fiber sequence $C_\ast(E/F,X) \to C_\ast(E,X) \to C_\ast(F,X)$.

By a theorem of Ganea, the induced map $E/F \to M$ has fiber $\Omega M \wedge \Sigma F$, so it's typically very far from an equivalence. But if $F$ is a homology disk, then it's an equivalence (so we get a fiber sequence $C(M,X) \to C(E,X) \to C(F,X)$ for all $X$).  <strike>Or if $M$ is aspherical, then $E/F \to M$ is a covering space, so that we get a fiber sequence $C(M,X) \to C(E,X) \to C(F,X)$ whenever $X$ is simply-connected.</strike>

Comment: In your first paragraph, the fiber over the component of $C(F,X)$ containing the constant map is actually the space of pointed maps $C_*(E/F,X)$, which muddies things every so slightly.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, so just to clarify things for myself, what exactly is a homology disk? I can't seem to find a definition. And when we have a fiber sequence, this implies an long exact sequence as I want it to be, in homotopy groups, right?

Comment: @PaulCusson By a homology disk, I mean to say $F$ is a space with the homology of a point, so that $\Sigma F$ is contractible. And the fiber sequence does give a long exact sequence of homotopy groups. I also realized that the case of $M$ being aspherical is more complicated than I was saying, sorry about that!

Comment: @Tyrone Thanks, I switched to talking about pointed maps everywhere now.

Comment: In the situation I'm working with $F = S^1$, and the bundle is a principal $S^1$-fiber bundle, with $M$ and $X$ simply connected. I'm sure these hypotheses are still too weak to say much that is meaningful, but is there something to work with here?